# Assertion error when passing object by value -- it is my copy constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, assertions

everyone!

I just finished writing a 2-D maze (Class is an ADT titled "Maze"--how original) that uses dynamic memory allocation. I'm passing the Maze to a method of another class I've entitled "MazeSolver," which uses recursion and backtracking to solve the maze. Good news is my code compiles wonderfully when I pass the object by reference.  News that I don't know if is good or bad is that I get an assertion error if I try to pass the Maze to MazeSolver by value.

Given that the error occurs only when I pass by value, I can only assume it has something to do with my copy constructor.  Before going any further, here's some info on the code:

Maze is composed of squares.  Each square is represented by a struct called SquareData.

```
      struct SquareData 
    {
        //data fields for the struct (NO POINTERS)
    }
```

I've decided to represent the entire maze with a vector of SquareData pointers (this vector is in private section of the class "Maze").

```
vector<SquareData*> squares;
```

Implementation of my destructor looks like this (that last call referencing a Player class is just eliminating a dangling pointer I have declared as a static variable for that class, which I have pointing at the maze. I don't think it's important considering the question, but I am new to C++ after all and one of you may think it might be, so I've included it for "hmmms"):

```
// clears maze of its contents
void Maze::clear() {
    int totalSquares = squares.size();
    for (int loopVar = 0; loopVar < totalSquares; loopVar++)
    {
        delete squares[loopVar]; // deallocate memory by deleting the square structure
        squares[loopVar] = nullptr; // eliminate dangling pointer
    } // vector takes care of itself
} // end clear

Maze::~Maze(){
    //clear the maze of contents (vector is full of pointers whose memory is on the heap)
    clear();
    //vector safe to deallocate itself now
    Player::setMaze(nullptr); // remove the pointer from player
}
```

I've declared the copy constructor in header as follows:

```
/** Copy Constructor */
    Maze(const Maze& myMaze);
```

with attempted implementation:

```
/** copy constructor */
Maze::Maze(const Maze& myMaze){
    /** Initialize Constants */
    mazeLength = myMaze.mazeLength;
    mazeWidth = myMaze.mazeWidth;
    exitRow = myMaze.exitRow;
    exitCol = myMaze.exitCol;
    entRow = myMaze.entRow;
    entCol = myMaze.entCol;
    /** copy the vector of pointers*/
    for (int loopVar = 0; loopVar < myMaze.squares.size(); loopVar++)
    {
        squares.push_back(myMaze.squares[loopVar]);
    }
} // end copy constructor
```

Here's how I attempted to understand what the problem was doing:

I wrote this vector display function in for my Maze class.

```
void Maze::vectorDisplay() const {
    for (int loopVar = 0; loopVar < squares.size(); loopVar++)
    {
        cout << "Vector Index: " << loopVar << endl;
        cout << "Pointer: " << squares[loopVar] << endl;
        cout << "Row: " << squares[loopVar]->Row << endl;
        cout << "Col: " << squares[loopVar]->Col << endl;
        cout << "State: " << squares[loopVar]->State << endl;
    }
} //end vectorDisplay
```

And found that the vector displays correctly when doing the following in the driver:

```
    Maze myMazeObject(// parameters);
    myMazeObject.vectorDisplay();
```

and will produce output with no complaints.

But now if I try to use code like this when passing by value:

```
Maze myMazeObject(// parameters);
MazeSolver myMazeSolver;
myMazeSolver.someMazeSolverMethod(myMazeObject);
```

where someMazeSolverMethod has the line `myMazeObject.vectorDisplay();`I get an assertion error just as the final element in the vector is being printed.

I want to say this is my fault and my copy constructor is a p.o.s.  If any insight, please let me know how to fix it and what I can do in the future!

Thanks for taking the time to read and even more so to answer should you choose to!

-J

Comment: Read up on the [rule of 3, rule of 5, and rule of 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction!  The copy assignment operator is news to me and I can see it solving a lot of problems for me in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of

```
    squares.push_back(myMaze.squares[loopVar]);
```

in the copy constructor will lead to problems downstream.That will be vaild had the contents of `squares` been objects not pointers.

There are now two objects holding on to the pointers. Both willl try to call `delete` on the same pointer, which easily leads to undefined behavior.

You can fix the problem by:

1. Using a `vector` objects instead of a `vector` of pointers, or
2. Creating new objects from the heap and adding them to the new object.

   ```
   squares.push_back(new SquareData(*myMaze.squares[loopVar]));
   ```

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I can see that you've dereferenced my original pointer and created a new object on the heap.  Via memory management, I can trust that two separate destructors will then also exist so that both the copy and the original are deleted once life ends?

Comment: @JoshuaMacvey, the last sentence can be phrased better but I think you understand the solution, and the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem.

```
    squares.push_back(myMaze.squares[loopVar]);
```

Basically each Maze has a vector full of the same pointers. When one copy of the maze goes out of scope it will delete all the pointers. Thus the other Maze now has a set of invalid pointers.

Couple of solutions.

1. Don't use pointers.

Unless you `SquareData` is polymorphic there seems no reason to keep pointers.

```
 std::vector<SquareData> squares;
```

2. If you want each copy of the maze to refer to the same squares.

Then use a shared pointer. This will keep a count of the number of references to each `SquareData` and thus only delete them when they truly go out of scope.

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SquareData>> squares;
```

3. Least attractive (and probably not needed).

Change the code to actually copy the pointer content into a new object.

```
squares.push_back(new SquareData(myMaze.squares[loopVar]));
```

Comment: Good point about the polymorphic qualities:  there really aren't any I can foresee using via the Maze class.  For my own knowledge, though, say I use a shared pointer.  If all the references are pointing to the same memory allocated on the heap, would I get an error after the life of the original ends and the copy attempts to deallocate that same memory?  Either way, I suppose some shared pointer studying is in order!  Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaMacvey: Shared pointer basically does ref counting on the pointer. Once the ref count reaches zero then the object is deleted. Thus it is safe to use from any number of other objects.

Comment: @JoshuaMacvey: But `SquareData` is not polymorphic why pay the cost of dynamic memory allocation. Just use a normal object in the vector. That is what you normally see in C++